# MySQL Calculate sum of integer values from one column and store the result in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I will start with saying I'm new to mysql and I haven't found any answer for my problem here, nor couldn't remake other examples by myself.

I have a table called "profiles" where I store my users, and one of the columns is "points" which stores integers.

I have a second table called "pointsCounter" with only one column "pointsTotal" (also integer) which stores only points from every user on site.

**I would like to sum up every user "points" in "profiles" and store the result in "pointsTotal" in table "pointsCounter".** I'm making the query using php to then echo the result to file that requests data with ajax.

Example:

```
profiles

id         |    points    |
---------------------------
1          |     10       |
2          |     20       |
3          |     0        |
4          |     40       |

pointsCounter

pointsTotal  |
--------------
70           |
```

This is my current not complete php code:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT points FROM profiles";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);  //$mysqli is my connection defined in db_connect
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $points = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
echo $points['pointsTotal'];
```

Comment: why are you adding up everything from profiles table and putting it in pointsCounter ? I don't think this design would be useful. To get points total every time, use SELECT SUM(points) from profiles

Comment: the thought was to have a place separate from profiles where I already have required informations and points of each user, to then distribute points to both specific users and shared "bank" which I will display in status bar, something like common goal, but now that I think about it I indeed dont need this table, but only calculating on the spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably best handled as a query.  Use the `SUM()` sql function to sum all the points together in the query, as "pointTotal".  The rest of the code should work fine.

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(points) AS pointTotal
FROM profiles"; 

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);  //$mysqli is my connection defined in db_connect

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $points = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
echo $points['pointTotal'];
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how this AS work? Do I need to make another column somewhere in profiles called pointsTotal or is this like an imaginary thing for me to temporary store value somewhere? because now It gives no difference

Comment: No, you telling the query to return the results from the `sum()` as a value named "pointTotal".  In fact you can tell a query to define a name for any value of your query.  Ex. `select users from Users AS myUsers`.  All of the users returned by the query will be under the `myUsers` field in the results array.

Comment: ooh, thats great! now I get it, it's really usefull knowledge, also I found out I've had a typo, your code works, thank you very much!

Comment: Good, Im glad it worked for you.  This is a really useful idea when standardizing field name s across your project.  That way all your field names have the same name despite what your database column names may be named.